# Convert date format DD/MM/YYYY to DD/MM/YY using Excel-formula

Tags: excel

I need to convert the date format DD/MM/YYYY to DD/MM/YY **using formulas** in Excel. The key thing is that it can't be in "text" format after the formula is done.

I have tried with

```
= IF( CELL("type", $A2) = "v",  $A2, VALUE(DAY(DATEVALUE($A2))&"/"&MONTH(DATEVALUE($A2))&"/"&YEAR(DATEVALUE($A2))-2000))
```

where cell A2 has the text "15/11/2019". My goal is to convert it into 15/10/19 (Excel DATEVALUE and VALUE functions keeps converting 19 into 2019).

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Change the Number format of the cell using a custom format of `dd/mm/yy`

Comment: It doesn't matter how you convert the date with formulas, the output of the date is dependent on the cell format only.

Comment: thanks for confirming my suspicion!

Answer (score 0):

An actual date in Excel (not text that looks like a date) is stored as a number.

It is the number of days since 1/1/1900.

What you see is just this number formatted in a user readable way.

To change this custom formatting from  DD/MM/YYYY to DD/MM/YY, got to the formatting menu on the "Home" tab:

[image]

And select "More Number Formats". Then select "Custom", and enter "dd/mm/yy" in the "Type:" field and click OK:

[image]